# Command line arguments

Tags: java, arrays, command-line, command-line-arguments

I've been doing some exercises from my study book, and I can't seem to figure out this specific one. The instructions are: repeat Exercise P7.2, but allow the user to specify the file name on the command line. If the user does not specify any file name, then prompt the user for the name.

Ín P7.2, which I've completed, we were supposed to write a program that reads a file containing text, read each line and send it to the output file, preceded by line numbers. Basically, what I'm wondering is what I'm supposed to do exactly?

This is my code right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name of file for reading: ");
    String fileNameReading = input.next(); 
    System.out.print("Enter name of file for writing: ");
    String fileNameWriting = input.next(); om
    input.close();

    File fileReading = new File(fileNameReading); 

    Scanner in = null; 
    File fileWriting = new File(fileNameWriting);

    PrintWriter out = null; 

    try {
        in = new Scanner(fileReading); 
        out = new PrintWriter(fileWriting); fileWriting
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Files are not found!");
    }

    int lineNumber = 1;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        out.write(String.format("/* %d */ %s%n", lineNumber, line));
        lineNumber++;
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Filen was read and re-written!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your exercise just requires a small refactor to use the command line arguments to specify the file for reading:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileNameReading;
    // check if input file were passed as a parameter
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        fileNameReading = args[0];
    }
    // if not, then prompt the user for the input filename
    else {
        System.out.print("Enter name of file for reading: ");
        fileNameReading = input.next();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter name of file for writing: ");
    String fileNameWriting = input.next();

    // rest of your code as is
}
```

You would run your code, for example, as:

```
java YourClass input.txt
```

Here we pass in the name of the input file as a parameter.

Comment: And a small change for *If the user does not specify any file name, then prompt the user for the name*

Comment: So do I run the code in the  cmd? Also, a secondary instructions was to pass arguments to the program via Run / Run configurations /Arguments. The arguments are meant to be assigned to the string, but when I tried typing an argument it just said that the file was not found.

Comment: 1) yes, run from the command prompt, or maybe from your IDE, 2) you might need to pass the absolute path to your file, if you don't know what the relative path would need to be.  That is, you might need to pass something like `C:/path/to/your/inputfile.txt`

Comment: Okay, I had to pass the absolute path but it works. I don't know what the instructions want me to do specifically? Which of the files should I run, and which file will get the arguments?

Comment: I also don't know, hence my answer only allows you to enter the _input_ filename from the command line.  A good follow-up exercise for you would be to also allow the output filename.  You will have to decide how to handle the case where someone enters only one filename, and how you want to interpret that use case.  Obviously, with no inputs, you would be forced to use the scanner to get both filenames.